# Can I use Ruby or Python library in Android Java application?

Tags: java, android, python, ruby

Let's say I want to write a poker app for Android.
It is fine to use APIs in Java. But when it comes to heavy usage of arrays, sets, combinations etc Java becomes a huge pain for me. It's much easier to code poker AI in Ruby/Python *IMHO*.

So the question: is there a way to use either Ruby or Python functions in Java Android Application? It should be packed in .apk of course.

**UPDATE:** Regarding Ruboto: As I understand from this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ruboto.core&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwib3JnLnJ1Ym90by5jb3JlIl0. ruboto-core needs to be installed on device to run ruboto apps =( It's no good if I'm going to share my app on Google Play.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [RhoMobile Suite](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Software+and+Applications/RhoMobile+Suite). It is a framework to write cross platform apps using Ruby. It has been acquired by Motorola Solutions but is still open-source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [JRuby](http://jruby.org/)? It's an open-source implementation of Ruby on top of Java that lets you use the JDK libraries. You could embed a JRuby instance into your app and run your logic using that.

Also see [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)

Comment: @ArtemIce: I did, and I'm talking about embedding JRuby **in** your app.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work. I tried the same with JPython and a Javascript interpreter, but both are directly creating JVM bytecode, which you can't run on an Android device (It has to be converted to Dalvik bytecode first).

Comment: @danielkullmann: There is a solution. Use JRuby to convert to JVM bytecode, and then use the Davlik converter of JVM to Davlik.

Comment: @Linuxios OK, didn't know that. I was also more referring to running the script code directly on the Android device, which is not what the OP actually asked about...

Comment: @danielkullmann: Not sure if that would work though. It might though. Don't know enough about JRuby/Java to say.

Comment: @danielkullmann: Here's the other thing. If you could just "copy/paste" the JRuby source into your project and ask it to interpret some Ruby code at runtime. You see, JRUby supports multiple modes. Interpreted, JIT, etc. JIT might work, but only if it generates JVM bytecode that can them be converted to Davlik.

Comment: **RE:** `see Jython` - As of 2016-06-18, the [**Jython FAQ**](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo#Can_I_use_Jython_to_make_apps_for_mobile_phones.3F) states: `Can I use Jython to make apps for mobile phones? Unfortunately not. Mobile phones only have Java ME (Micro Edition) but Jython requires Java SE (Standard Edition). There is no Jython port to ME, and there is not enough interest to make it worth the effort.`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Ruboto](http://ruboto.org/)?
It claims to run Ruby scripts in Android devices!

Comment: If you don't want to redirect Android users to Ruboto download page, you can probably try to embed JRuby in your app, as @Linuxios suggested. Although it will probably make your app somewhat bigger.

Answer (score 1):

There's this that might help you though, scripting Layer for Android SL4A found [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/), Though am not sure exactly how you'd integrate it with Android SDK :)

Actually, on reading the wiki, in the FAQ and quote:

> Can I use SL4A to write a real Android application or embed SL4A
>   scripts in my application? Yes! You can embed your script in a
>   (mostly) stand alone APK.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/), which let you include a python distribution in your android application, the distribution could include module you want to use.